# Visual Studio Code Run Without Debugging seems to be pointing to the last executed path

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, makefile, compiler-errors

I have a root folder with three folders each containing a project (Project1a, Project1b, and Project2).

Project1a and Project1b consist of a single `.c` file with `int main()` while Project2 contains multiple `.c` files with proper `#include "filename.h"` statements and `int main()`.

I am able to select Run -> Run Without Debugging in VS Code for Project1 and Project1b with the following output (Project1 is shown as an example):

```
/usr/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/github/dir/project1a/proj.c -o /home/github/dir/project1a/proj1

Build finished successfully.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

But when I try to run the (only) file containing `int main()` from Project2, I get the following:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/github/dir/project2/proj/failed.c -o /home/github/dir/project2/proj/failed
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cctv17Uz.o: in function `main':
/home/github/dir/project2/proj/failed.c:25: undefined reference to `init_tokenizer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/github/dir/project2/proj/failed.c:26: undefined reference to `get_next_token'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/github/dir/project2/proj/failed.c:30: undefined reference to `free_tokenizer'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status



Breakpoint 1, main (argc=21845, argv=0x0) at /home/github/dir/project1a/proj.c:27
27  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
[Inferior 1 (process 7717) exited normally]
The program '/home/github/dir/project1a/proj' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

What's in the undefined reference error message are precisely those files in the `#include "filename.h"`.
Upon closer inspection, I am noticing that it is **pointing to Project1a instead of Project2.**

If I run Project1b with Run -> Run Without Debugging, the error message will point to Project1b.

This makes me suspect that VS Code is somehow caching the path, although it does not explain why I am able to run Project1a and Project1b.

Is my suspicion sound, and if so, is there a setting in VS Code that will help with this issue?

Not sure if it's relevant, but for Project2b, I have a `Makefile` that I can successfully use with `make all` to produce a runnable file in the terminal, but neither Project1a nor Project1b have a `Makefile.`

Comment: VSCode only compiles the file in the editor. If you have split your code in multiple files you must compile all of them. Update `task.json` accordingly.  Also, the only reference to project1 is the location of a breakpoint. Of course, that stays in the same file where you've put it.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks for the comment. I looked into `task.json`, and I was able to get the project to compile by listing all of the necessary files like this `"${workspaceFolder}/github/dir/project2/project2.c"`. Though, I am unable to use the wildcard functionality`"${workspaceFolder}/github/dir/project2/*.c"` to save time somehow.

Comment: What's interesting is that without changing the `task.json` file, I noticed that if I include the corresponding `.c` file in additional to the `.h` file, VS Code works too. I thought including `.h` file is all I need.

Comment: Technically, you can do this as well. But it is considered bad style. Any static variable will be visible in the include file as well. You should really not do this. Make sure you build all source files and link them together.